# How do I auto sign in to Laravel via an API coming from .net?

Tags: asp.net, laravel, rest

We have a portal built in asp.net and we need one of the sections to be an embedded frame containing a webapp built in Laravel, however the Laravel webapp has a login and we dont want users having to login twice. So how do I set this up? I understand I need to use this method : 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

The request would be coming from .net and I would parse say the JSON response, but how do I setup laravel to consume that API call? I have never done anything like this before and I dont know where to start. Can someone explain or give me a series of steps? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you have the user id as `$id`, you can use:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id);
```